# Bypass required module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Sometimes I can't find updated type definition files when I'm working with a new version of a node package. For example, I'm unable to find a recent type definition file for Mongoose. So I get errors when I try to use it. So I'm trying to figure out a way to bypass the error I get from this line:

```
import mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

The error is `Cannot find module 'mongoose'`. How can I tell the TypeScript compiler, and Visual Studio, that I have loaded the module I just don't have type definitions for it?

Comment: Try `declare var mongoose:any`

Comment: @MikeSW I've used that to bypass external libraries on the client side, when I don't need to do an import. But this doesn't seem to have any affect on `require("...")` statements. I tried putting it before and after the statement, no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [write a declaration file](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html) to provide TypeScript with type definitions for external libraries. Since this is an npm module, you should use the `declare module 'modulename' { }` syntax:

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
    var mongoose: any; // probably want to make this more specific
    export = mongoose;
}
```

Put that inside a `mongoose.d.ts` file and include it in your code with:

```
/// <reference path="mongoose.d.ts" />
```

Comment: yup, this is one is better than mine solution because you don't have to fork the library

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick and add typings to the library. As TypeScript definition says (http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typings-for-npm-packages.html) - it tries to to find `typings` definition in `package.json` file, if definition is not there then it tries to lad `index.d.ts` file inside project library.

My solution is bit silly, fork the repository, point your project `packages.json` to your forked repo, add `index.d.ts` file with some "mock" typings.